# Using an HTML link to logout and abandon the session

Tags: html, asp.net

I was previously using an ASP button which on the 'OnClick' method it abandoned the session and redirected the page. However i am now using this usercontrol within a page with no server forms and must use an HTML Link. How can i access the onclick method previosuly used? or how can i use the html link to abandon the session and redirect now?

Comment: Use jquery ajax, or pagemethods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a page called `Logout.aspx`. In `OnLoad` method of this page do what you previously do in `OnClick` method. Open `Logout.aspx` when user clicks HTML Link.

Something like

```
<a href="Logout.aspx">Logout</a>

protected void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Abandon session and redirect
}
```

Comment: You beat me by a second! :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Use that link to navigate to a separate page say logout.aspx. In the code-behind of that page, fire `session.abandon` and `server.redirect`.